# C programming (conditional operators) question

Tags: c

So the output here is no... I just don't get what's happening here... Can anyone help?

```
   #include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int a=15,b=10,c=0;
    if(a&&b&&c)
    printf("Yes");
    else
    printf("No");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well `c` is `0` so that makes the condition false. Anything and'ed with 0 is false.

Comment: What other did you expect?

Comment: There are two things you need to know. 1) `&&` is logical AND. 2) 0 is `false`, and any non-zero value is `true`. Put those together, the condition is `(true AND true AND false)` which is false. If that's not clear, then you should search for a tutorial on "boolean algebra".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is going to be "no" as the third value, c, is equal to 0. `&&` statements return true as long as all conditions are true inside of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
if (a && b && c)
```

is the same as

```
if ((a != 0) && (b != 0) && (c != 0))
```

Since *c == 0*, as stated before, the evaluation of the expression is false, hence the answer is "No".